# WordPress 3.7.1 Admin Incompatible with XDebug?

Tags: wordpress, xdebug

XDebug appears to block the WordPress admin area from loading.

Has anyone else seen that? Does someone have a fix?

This is:
Mac OS X 10.9
MAMP Pro 2.2
WordPress 3.7.1
PHP 5.5.3
Xdebug 2.2.3

Xdebug is launched with:

zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so

Bob

Comment: What is the output that you are getting?

Comment: Derick - I get the White Screen Of Death. Is there an appropriate log to be looking for errors in?

Comment: Check your Apache log file, it should have an error. You can also make a PHP error log with the settings: display_errors=0, log_errors=1, error_log=/tmp/php.log and error_reporting=-1 — they should go into the /tmp/php.log file.